# Mixed numbers with 'normal' size

Tags: fractions

I want to achieve look like this: 
[image]

I tried some packages but there is big size difference.

some clean code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
$7$
$\dfrac{1}{6}=$
$\dfrac{42+1}{6}=$
$\dfrac{43}{6}$

\end{document}
```

Comment: it isn't clear what your question is, Perhaps it would help if you made the example use the same fractions as the image you show, and you said what parts you wanted to change

Comment: Ok, I want what is on the picture. I will change some lines. I want the fraction of the mixed number to be centered with the others.

Comment: But the code you show [makes this output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s1aGK.png) if extended to those fractions, how do you want that to change?

Comment: are you sure you want the fraction rule aligned with the bottom one of sign equal?

Comment: why are you starting and stopping math mode? the output I show above is from your output but with all the `$` removed and  it set more naturally as a single display `[..\]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not clear what your question is so I offer two alternatives

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

Either
\[
  7\frac{1}{6}=\frac{42+1}{6}=\frac{43}{6}
\]
or
\begin{center}
$ 7\frac{1}{6}=\frac{42+1}{6}=\frac{43}{6}$  
\end{center}


\end{document}
```

I can't see any cases where you would want to set this as multiple math fragments in separate `$...$` also avoid using `\dfrac` in most uses of inline math.

Comment: Thank you! For the $ - anything, i dont even type like that. But sometimes i need to add some text (one char) in cyrillic and i need to separate them. But not in that case.

Comment: @SimeonSimeonov glad you found the answer useful, I still have no idea what your question is though:-)

Comment: I didn't know you can type mixed numbers like that with 7\frac..

Comment: @SimeonSimeonov ? I haven't use `\dfrac` at all here. so I don't understand the comment about using dfrac inside frac? In fact it is almost always better to use `\frac` than `\dfrac`, just use `\dfrac` in very rare cases that you need to over-ride the the default size choice.

Comment: Ah, I didn't know that. I am using \dfrac everywhere because it's bigger..

Comment: @SimeonSimeonov it is the _wrong_ size,  which is presumably why you asked the question!